# Unable to connect to a local MYSQL server on wireles LAN

Tags: mysql, connection

Ok, Here is the technical description.
My laptop's config:
Ip Adress:192.168.2.5
Mysqlserver 5.0 on port : 3306
Operating system: Ubuntu jaunty (9.04)
3306 is open for both incoming and outgoing.

My friend's laptop config:
Ip Adress:192.168.2.4 
Mysqlserver 5.0 on port : 3306
Operating system: Windows XP pro
3306 is open for both incoming and outgoing.

Both are on a wireless LAN connected through a belkin router (192.168.2.1)

Both the MYSQL servers have been given the sufficient **GRANT** privileges. I am also able to connect from 192.168.2.4 to 192.168.2.5's MYSQL instance but the vice versa is not happening. I am getting an (100061) error. Tried Telnetting on 3306; again happening from 192.168.2.4 to 192.168.2.5 but not the vice versa. Am I doing something wrong?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: post the output of "netstat -na|findstr LISTEN" run on the Windows system (in a cmd shell).

Comment: TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:2425           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

Comment: you should ask this on serverfault.com you may have better answers

Comment: Thanks, Will try there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Is the mysql server of your friend accepting connections other then from localhost?
Although i think this quest needs to be moved to serverfault.

Comment: Don't know actually. the 'bind-address' in the my.cnf is commented out, so i guess it should accept connections other than the localhost.

Comment: And the host file of windows?

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to use "flush privileges" after new grant statement; this has burnt me many times.

Comment: "flush privileges" given. problem is still there.

Comment: This is only required when you modify the grant tables manually, not when you use the GRANT statement.